# MySQL - A lot of columns in a Table - needs suggestions

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to ask for sugestions about one of my database table. Below is the `create` statement for my table named `io_generated` where it contains **30+ columns**. My question is is it good to have columns like this or should I separate some of the data in a different table? I am using VB.net to insert data in my database and I'm using OOP. Is this a good practice? Or is there anyway or suggestion in order to create a beatiful table?

The table contained `8 logs`, 4 time in, and 4 out logs. Each log have `branch_id` (branch1...branch8) and I also have a column to determine if the `log is edited` (in1_edited...out4_edited), and there is also the computation of `Late`, `Undertime` and `total working hours`. All of it in this table.

Thank you in advance! Your help is fully appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE `io_generated` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employee_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `branch_id` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `in1` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `out1` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `in2` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `out2` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `in3` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `out3` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `in4` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `out4` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `branch1` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `branch2` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `branch3` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `branch4` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `branch5` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `branch6` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `branch7` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `branch8` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `in1_edited` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `out1_edited` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `in2_edited` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `out2_edited` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `in3_edited` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `out3_edited` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `in4_edited` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `out4_edited` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `late1` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `late2` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `late3` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `late4` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `total_late` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `hrs1` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `hrs2` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `total_whrs` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `ot_hrs` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `ut1` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `ut2` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `ut3` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `ut4` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `total_ut` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `day_count` double(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `employee_id` (`employee_id`,`id`,`date`,`branch_id`),
  KEY `branch_id` (`branch_id`),
  KEY `branch1` (`branch1`),
  KEY `branch2` (`branch2`),
  KEY `branch3` (`branch3`),
  KEY `branch4` (`branch4`),
  KEY `branch5` (`branch5`),
  KEY `branch6` (`branch6`),
  KEY `branch7` (`branch7`),
  KEY `branch8` (`branch8`),
  CONSTRAINT `io_generated_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`employee_id`) REFERENCES `employee` (`Employee_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `io_generated_ibfk_10` FOREIGN KEY (`branch8`) REFERENCES `branch` (`Branch_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `io_generated_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`branch_id`) REFERENCES `branch` (`Branch_ID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `io_generated_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`branch1`) REFERENCES `branch` (`Branch_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `io_generated_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`branch2`) REFERENCES `branch` (`Branch_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `io_generated_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`branch3`) REFERENCES `branch` (`Branch_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `io_generated_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`branch4`) REFERENCES `branch` (`Branch_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `io_generated_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`branch5`) REFERENCES `branch` (`Branch_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `io_generated_ibfk_8` FOREIGN KEY (`branch6`) REFERENCES `branch` (`Branch_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `io_generated_ibfk_9` FOREIGN KEY (`branch7`) REFERENCES `branch` (`Branch_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The In1 to Out4 is Related to Branch1 to Branch 8 and In1_edited to Out4_edited. Each In/Out have corresponding branches and edit identifier.

Comment: This is hard to answer, because we don't know the relations exactly. The table doesn't look good on first glance, but may still be the appropriate model. Let's start with the table's natural key. Can there be one row per employee and date in the table? Or one per employee, date and branch ID? Or what else is the unique key (apart from the added surrogate `id`)? Then, there are always exactly for "in" and "out" or up to 4? And `late1` refers to `in1` or `out1` or both? and `total_late` is just the sum of `late1` to `late4` or smething else? ...

Comment: And `hrs1` refer to `in1` or to all ins and outs or to what else? And how can there be a `day_count` when a row refers to one  `date`? This cannot be the number of days, but some thing counted for that day then? And what do the `branch1` to `branch8` belong to? All ins and outs or only certain ones? Is it always exactly 8 branches or up to 8? ... You will have to explain in detail for us to be able to help you here?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I edited my `create statement` and added the unique keys which are `UNIQUE KEY `employee_id` (`employee_id`,`id`,`date`,`branch_id`)`.

Comment: And is it guanranteed that there can never be more than four ins and four outs and eight branches in the years to come?

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) should help you normalize your table.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes it will be only 8 logs and 8 branches.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc: Normalization would only remove the computations from the table, however. Most of the table would stay the same. in1, in2, in3, in4 don't violate any normal form I am aware of and can be a reasonable way to store the data. This design can even be more suitable than the more typical design with a parent and child table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not store computed values in your table. This violates database normalization, because you store values redundantly. Example: If a table contains the columns x and y and x_plus_y and their values in a table row are 10, 12, and 13, then some person or process has inserted invalid data, because 10+12=22, not 13. Maybe the values were correct at first, but then one of the values was updated and the updating person or process was not aware that they had to update the dependent column, too. Anyway, now some queries may use x_plus_y and others may calculate the result from x and y, and thus they give different results. That must not be.

The solution to that: Don't store the values, when you can always calculate them ad hoc. You can, however, write a view or add generated columns to your table. Generated columns are mere calcuations that either get done when queried or when their base values change. E.g.

```
create table io_generated
(
  ...
  total_late decimal(10,2) generated always as (late1 + late2 + late3 + late4) virtual;
  ...
);
```

(Exception to the rule: In data warehouses we often accept redundancy. We usually get our data from a database without redundancies and introduce the redundancies in order to gain access speed.)

Apart from that your table looks okay. We cannot know, however, if its design is appropriate or not, because we know too little about your data. A more typical design would be:

```
CREATE TABLE io_generated 
(
  io_generated_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  employee_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  date DATE NOT NULL,
  branch_id MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE io_detail
(
  io_detail_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  io_generated_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  in_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL,
  out_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL,
  in_branch_id MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  out_branch_id MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  in_edited TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  out_edited TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

This design has advantages and disadvantages compared to yours.

- It's very easy for instance to tell whether there are IOs after 10 p.m., because it's just one database column we must look at. It's very difficult on the other hand to tell whether there are IOs after 10 p.m. for the third IO, because we'd first have to determine which detail row is third.
- It's very easy to extend this and have five IOs some day instead of only four. Just add a row; we would not have to change the table designs at all. It's very hard or impossible on the other hand to guarantee to have exactly four IOs.
- It's very easy to count how many distinct in-branches are involved (`COUNT(DISTINCT in_branch_id)`).
- It's impossible to guarantee all detail rows' dates match the parent row's date. This, however, can easily solved by switching from surrogate keys to natural composite keys.

I hope this helps you getting an idea what to consider when deciding for one design or the other.

Comment: Thank you. I'll put this in mind and apply it in my database tables.

Comment: Generated Columns are new to me and I can say that it is realy helpful. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your database should be normalized.
Try to reduce the number of columns and increase the number of tables.
for example:
Make separate tables for Employee,Branches,Timings
Use foreign keys to add data
that would be way more understandable than this